explanation for the unexpected completion behavior in minibuffer?
It is self-explanatory in the screenshots below. As an example, typing sgf does not show the all file names containing sgf? It only shows the candidate file name starting with sgf:

Instead, typing an extra whitespace is needed to show all the matching file names:

And I found it is even more unexpected with C-x 8 RET to enter Unicode character. Unlike the sgf example above, typing an extra whitespace does not show the Unicode names with "cross" in the middle:


I have to start with a whitespace to show all the characters that have "cross" in the middle of the name (note that there is a whitespace typed before the cursor):

This is my completion style config with orderless:
  (use-package orderless
    :ensure t
    :after pyim
    :config
    (advice-add 'orderless-regexp :around #'my-orderless-pyim-regexp)
    :custom
    (completion-styles '(orderless basic))
    (completion-category-overrides '((file (styles partial-completion))
                                     (references (styles partial-completion)))))


Your pdf example isn't equivalent if there isn't a file name starting with pdf, and your example shows no such file.  Please confirm how the behaviour differs.

Similarly, you'd need file names with spaces to have an equivalent situation to the unicode characters.  Please test accordingly.

That's exactly what I am asking (as stated in the if clause).

If you're not actually suggesting that there's something different or unusual about names containing pdf (or names containing sgf) vs any other possible filename, then you could make that clearer.  You seem to be making a specific comparison.  If your question is specifically about "search pattern matches filename extension" vs "search pattern matches elsewhere in filename" then you should say so clearly.

Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with emacs -Q? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. What's your value of completion-styles etc.?

The completion-styles value is already listed '(orderless basic).

hmm, the pdf example may be distracting. I edited my question and hope it is clear now.

Have you tried removing the advice?

yes. removing the advice did not help.

In the following, I’ll refer to this page.
Note that the same documentation is available in Emacs help system (C-h i) if you have version 29.x.
orderless works as follows:

If the regex is first and requested in configuration, it starts and returns the first occurrence of the pattern typed by the user.
If the pattern can occur multiple times, orderless can find these occurrences by searching the pattern as a substring. However, the user must specify this substring by adding a space before and/or after the pattern.

This is consistent with your examples. In the first picture, the file name starts with svg is found, and nothing else. The regex works. In the second picture, you added a space and found the substring svg in many other instances. While you describe this as all names, a better expression would be ‘extensions’. Consider using the prefixing dot to search, e.g., .svg.
For the third case (pictures 3, 4, 5), the same applies. You can also use the search pattern SPCcrossSPC for more items.
orderless filters in smaller chunks as needed by the user, which can be an advantage for faster results or a disadvantage if it breaks your thinking when looking for a specific pattern. If you find this package difficult to use, you can configure Emacs to use it with the company package. See the explanations under the heading Company in the linked page or use only the company package.

I had skimmed thru the orderless manual but didn't see anything about space required for "component" vs. "prefix". orderless has ^ to specify orderless-literal-prefix to match prefix. Thus it is a bit confusing (at least to me). Even so, why I need a space before "cross" in the 3rd example? Won't a space after "cross" enough to set "cross" as search component to match the candidates with "cross" in the middle?

orderless-literal-prefix is restrictive - it returns only the strings that matches
the pattern starting at index 0, i.e at the beginning of the string. Try also the default
minimal configuration (setq completion-styles '(orderless basic)) without overrides. And the
pattern SPCcrossSPC will add around ten new items.

Thanks. I think I now understand how it works. Removal of partial-completion works like what I originally expected - treating each word without space as a component. However, I still have trouble understanding what causes the difference in candidates generated by pattern SPCcrossSPC vs. crossSPC...

They are different patterns. Did you checked them both?

yes, I checked both patterns
